# Pandas datetime strange behaviour by time selection with string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following datetime series:

```
0   2021-05-19 00:00:00
1   2021-05-19 00:00:00
2   2021-05-19 00:00:00
3   2021-05-19 00:00:00
4   2021-05-19 00:00:00
5   2021-05-19 23:59:00
6   2021-05-19 23:59:00
7   2021-05-19 23:59:00
8   2021-05-19 23:59:00
9   2021-05-19 23:59:00
Name: Ab, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If I use this selection method:

```
s[s.dt.date == datetime.date(2021, 5, 19)]
```

I get all data:

```
0   2021-05-19 00:00:00
1   2021-05-19 00:00:00
2   2021-05-19 00:00:00
3   2021-05-19 00:00:00
4   2021-05-19 00:00:00
5   2021-05-19 23:59:00
6   2021-05-19 23:59:00
7   2021-05-19 23:59:00
8   2021-05-19 23:59:00
9   2021-05-19 23:59:00
Name: Ab, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But if I use this short one:

```
s[s == '2021-05-19']
```

I get only midnight samples:

```
0   2021-05-19
1   2021-05-19
2   2021-05-19
3   2021-05-19
4   2021-05-19
Name: Ab, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

What are the best practices to deal with such cases? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If compare by dates output is expected because only `date`s are compared by scalar `date`.

If compare by string then Pandas compares like `datetime` with `00:00:00` times, so the output is `2021-05-19 00:00:00`, but because all dates have the same `00:00:00` times they are not displayed.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please show a few safe ways to select samples by date?

Comment: @MykolaZotko - Can you explain more? Becayse if compare by dates pandas sometimes working with them like `datetime`s, so depends what exaclly need.

Comment: What is the short alternative to `s[s == '2021-05-19']` to select all samples from  '2021-05-19'?

Comment: @Mykola Zotko Use `s[s.dt.normalize() == '2021-05-19']` for remove times without convert to dates.